# How can I make a variable declared inside a "do" block valid in the "while"?

Tags: c#, while-loop

I wrote a code:

```
do
{
    string html = new StreamReader(response3.GetResponseStream(),
                                   Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
    if (html.Contains("link-censored"))
    {
        log("[!] Banned link\r\n");
        return -2; // delete url from txt
    }
    else if (html.Contains("data-with-image"))
    {
        log("[+] Add link\r\n");
    }
    else
    {
        log("[?] Smthng wrong with link\r\n");
        return -2; //-3
    }
}
while (html.Contains("data-with-image"));
```

But I have an error The name 'html' does not exist in the current context on the last line.

Answer (score 4):

`html` is scoped **inside** the `do {...}`; just move the declaration:

```
string html;
do
{
    html = new StreamReader(response3.GetResponseStream(),
                                   Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
    //...
}
while (html.Contains("data-with-image"));
```

Note we don't need to *assign* to `html` - since the rules of "definite assignment" guarantee it has a value by the time it gets to the `while`.

Comment: Thanks but I have get endless loop=\ [+] Add link [+] Add link [+] Add link [+] Add link [+] Add link But html.Contains("data-with-image") == true

Comment: @user1877127 making the code do what you want is an entirely separate question, that first requires some kind of specification of what it is meant to do. The question here was about the `html` variable not being available, which is what people have answered.

Comment: @user1877127 however, the fact that you do the same thing every time (read from response 3 etc) means that yes: it is likely to keep doing the same thing. Why do you expect it to **not** be an infinite loop, when you haven't (at least, not visibly) done anything that would cause it to exit the loop?

Answer (score 3):

The scope of string variable `html` is within body of `do-while loop`, Define html out side the loop body to make it accessible to `condition part`.

```
string html = string.Empty; 

do
{
    html = new StreamReader(response3.GetResponseStream(),
                                   Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
    if (html.Contains("link-censored"))
    {
        log("[!] Banned link\r\n");
        return -2; // delete url from txt
    }
    else if (html.Contains("data-with-image"))
    {
        log("[+] Add link\r\n");
    }
    else
    {
        log("[?] Smthng wrong with link\r\n");
        return -2; //-3
    }
}
while (html.Contains("data-with-image"));
```

Comment: Thanks but I have got endless loop=\ [+] Add link [+] Add link [+] Add link [+] Add link [+] Add link But html.Contains("data-with-image") == true How to exit from this loop if my get req returns html.Contains("data-with-image")

Comment: @user1877127 making the code do what you want is an entirely separate question, that first requires some kind of specification of what it is meant to do. The question here was about the html variable not being available, which is what people have answered.

Comment: Yes, this loop will execute forever WHILE the html contains "data-with-image". If you want it to loop UNTIL you get that, then you need to change your while condition to while(!html.Contains("data-with-image"));

Answer (score 1):

exit if you find your expected condition.

```
string html = string.Empty; 

do
{
    html = new StreamReader(response3.GetResponseStream(),
                                   Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
    if (html.Contains("link-censored"))
    {
        log("[!] Banned link\r\n");
        return -2; // delete url from txt
    }
    else if (html.Contains("data-with-image"))
    {
        log("[+] Add link\r\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        log("[?] Smthng wrong with link\r\n");
        return -2; //-3
    }
}
while (html.Contains("data-with-image"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the variable "html" only exist inside the loop.
Try to declare it just before the loop:

```
string html = null;
do {
    html = ...
    ...
} while(html.Contains("data-with-image"));
```